# Sending JavaScript variables to PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is the JavaScript:

```
var sendlat;
var sendlng;
var sendid;

// More code...

$.post('insert.php', {variable: sendlat});
$.post('insert.php', {variable: sendlng});
```

And this is the `insert.php` file:

```
$latitude = $_POST['sendlat'];
$longtitude = $_POST['sendlng'];
```

This is giving me 0 values. What do I need to change?

Comment: In your code snippet, you don't actually set the values of you variables. Probably just a copy/paste error though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your postdata variables are wrong, your insert.php recieves `$_POST['variable']` twice

Change code to:

```
$.post('insert.php', {sendlat: sendlat, sendlng: sendlng});
```

So you send this in one go instead.

Comment: actually, as he posted it would only receive variable once, but it would have a different value for each post call. Neither call would be aware of the other.

Comment: @KaiQing Ok, to be completely clear about OP's post: insert.php gets $_POST['variable'] once, but gets executed twice (as you say unaware of the other call). That was my point.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you didn't really go over the [jQuery docs for post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) here.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/insert.php',
  data: {sendlat: sendlat, sendlng: sendlng},
  success: function(data){
    //do something with your success
  }
});
```

For one, you do not need 2 post calls. That will separate the data.
Do it in one ajax call.

Secondly, as Charmander pointed out, you're sending it with the post variable "variable" which is wrong.

The left of colon is the post variable name. `sendlat:100` would result in `$_POST['sendlat'] = 100` in PHP.

Comment: nothing per say except it is just shorthand for ajax. I use ajax as this example because it is the first example in the post docs and likely easiest to follow if the OP chose to review the docs linked. No other reason. .post is perfectly acceptable if the syntax is correct and used as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the values to the variable named variable. This is the same as: index.php?variable=sendlat

Also, you could set both variables in one call to stop from doing extra hits on the server.

`$.post('insert.php', {sendlat: sendlat, sendlng: sendlng});`